# C# How to lock in abstract class with third parties

Tags: c#, multithreading, abstract

**Introduction**

I have a public abstract class, with an abstract method, which I want to call from a worker thread.

When the method is called, the respective instance should be locked down in order to prevent state changes during calculation.

I only want to work with the abstract class, as the implementation of the inheritors is done by third parties.

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    public abstract MyResult GetData();
}
```

**The problem**

My library is used by third parties, I have to assume that they know nothing about the internal implementation of the library.

I don't want to force them to study the documentation of my class, before they are able to implement their own inheritor as I consider this bad form.

**My approach**

My first idea was to add a protected lock object to the class and lock on it when calling the method.

However, in order for this to be useful, the third party would have to lock on it as well, and thus know about it.

As I don't want to force the third party to know about the internals, I don't like this option.

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    protected readonly object myLock = new object();

    public MyResult GetData()
    {
        MyResult result;

        lock(myLock)
        {
            result = GetDataInternal();
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected abstract MyResult GetDataInternal();
}
```

**Background**

I'm working on a data pipeline, which runs on a separate thread.

This pipeline requests data in a specific format and processes it in the background.

Providing the data can take some time and the provided data relies on properties of the objects.

In this case, its a preparation pipeline for 3D models.

**The question**

How can I lock a whole object without knowing its implementation?

If there is no such way, then is there an agreed upon pattern or something like that for this problem?

Comment: Just a comment. Forcing people that inherit from your types to read the documentation and follow the rules you've set forth is not bad form, it is **absolutely required**. Granted, you should make it easy for them to fall into the "pit of success" but you simply cannot make a type foolproof if you intend to let them inherit from your type. For all you know they could implement methods returning the negative of what you expect, throwing a big spanner into the works of any code using these descendant types.

Comment: There is no generalized lock that will "lock out code" from executing without that code also caring about the lock. In other words, if some code accesses the object without locking, and some code with, you can't magically make the first piece of code care about the lock without changing it. You can close down your object so as to only provide thread-safe access, such as only providing snapshots of its internals but this too requires changes to any 3rd party code that uses your type.

Comment: You are right, reading the documentation is a must. But here I dislike the requirement as intuitively most people would fail to recognize the myLock property. I dislike implementations which are (in most cases) only properly used when the documentation was read.

Comment: One more note - you can make `myLock` private. It's only used by your public method. No one inheriting the class needs to know it's there.

Comment: They need to know about it, as right now the only thing is does is preventing multiple simultaneous calls to "GetDataInternal". However, right now it doesn't prevent instance access by other threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My library is used by third parties, I have to assume that they know nothing about the internal implementation of the library.
>   (..)
>   When the method is called, the respective instance should be locked down in order to prevent state changes during calculation.

I think that the best way is to .. make them know, and make sure they know that they are responsible for it. You can easily make it intuitive without (much) documentation.

Consider changing your abstract class to something like:

```
public interface ILockable
{
    void FreezeDataForCalculations();
    void ThawAfterCalculations();
}

public abstract class MyBaseClass<T> where T:ILockable
{
    public abstract T GetData();
}
```

Usage:

```
public class MyThingie : MyBaseClass<TheActualData>
{
}

public class TheActualData : ILockable
{
    public string Foo {get;set;}

    public void FreezeDataForCalculations() { ...???...}
    public void ThawAfterCalculations() { ....???.... }
}
```

Now, you effectively ensured that:

- whoever wants to implement it, has to provide his own type, that implements extra interface
- whoever implementa that extra interface **will notice** this two methods, and they **will** at least think "wtf", and will either understand immediatelly, or will try consulting the documentation
- you do no locking for the data, creator of the class is responsible for it
- implementor now **can choose** whever to actually implement freeze/thaw pair, or leave them empty and simply write their own code to not modify the data in the meantime
- your code now has to call 'Freeze' and 'Thaw' appropriatelly, and can assume the implementor did what he was expected to

On the contrary, if you can't assume that he did was he was expected to, then change API of your library and don't allow user-defined types, and restrict the API to only your own types that you can ensure that will play nice.

Comment: This is beautifull and simple. If someone ignores this, then it's clearly their own fault. Looks like a great solution to me. Thank you!

Comment: I think that this is a step back from the original design. The question was about how to hide the locking behavior. The OP's code did just that. This does the opposite - exposing the need for a lock and making the consumer responsible. There may still be a way to improve on the original but it's accomplishing the intent. Someone inheriting the class can fill in the needed functionality but doesn't even need to know that there's locking going on.

Comment: Another way of looking at it - this requires someone to call methods that don't have any apparent relation to anything the class does. Any class, even a string, may need to be protected from changes in state from various threads. I don't recommend creating a pattern where we explicitly "mark" classes that need to be locked, implying that everything else is implicitly thread safe.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a step back. My original design would still need the consumer to implement the locking behaviour himself, as otherwise the lock wouldn't do anything usefull. The problem was, that I had a property, which could be overlooked easily, and thus lead to incorrect implementations from the consumer. The solution proposed by quetzalcoatl solves this problem.
Unless there's a way to lock the whole object, there's no other way than to make the consumer responsible.

Comment: @ScottHannen: I would agree with you, but you assume a bit too much. Say, what if this one data structure is the only thread-unsafe thing in the whole process? we don't know it. This 'downgraded' piece of code solves a certain problem. This problem **was not** about enforcing protection. The problem was about making the users of this code (who apparently don't fancy reading the docs) notice that there are concurrency and data mutation problems involved. This piece of code did it in a naive and flashy way, mostly to **get attention**.

Comment: I actually don't like this pattern. I am always tempted to roll out some cool and fancy management layer or transparent snapshotting of the data or (..). However, complexity and implementation cost is always a factor. When the point of contact between threaded and nonthreaded areas is simple and tiny, bloating the API with such things is .. disputable at least.

Comment: Btw. I am a bit surprised by your idea that someone may assume something to be implicitly thread safe. I probably won't be mistaken much if I say that in .Net, the tradition is that everything is implicitly thread unsafe unless specified otherwise. As for the pattern, take a look at Freezable in WPF for example. It denotes thread-safe things while others stay unsafe. It is a very clear design. Adding such piece of "synchronization" will not make anyone think that everything else is safe. Just the opposite. (yes, I know that Freezable works in a different way than here. But the idea is similar)

Comment: You're correct. Everything should be assumed to be non-thread-safe unless otherwise specified. That's the problem with explicitly indicating that class *isn't.* That being said, my answer was really just a stab at it based on what I could get from the question. I don't think that I really understand the scenario at all. Perhaps if there was code illustrating how a 3rd party library inherits from the class and then where and how that derived class is used. Without that complete picture I'm really just guessing.